# Interactive regex builder learn tool for Mac OS X?

Tags: regex, macos

Anyone want to recommend a good regex tool (Interactive GUI for constructing and learning) for regex syntax on Mac OS X?

Comment: Oyster (http://www.rwe-uk.com/app/Oyster) is a good one...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can recommend Patterns, found on Mac App Store:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/patterns-the-regex-app/id429449079?mt=12

Answer (score 3):

http://rubular.com. It's on the Internet, so you should be able to use it on OS X. It uses Ruby's regexp engine, but that is similar enough to Perl and other regexp engines.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't know of any native OS X "interactive" regex tools, here are a couple of good visual regex match tools:

- [Reggy](http://reggyapp.com/) ([screenshot](http://reggyapp.com/images/screenshots/1.3/main.png))
- [Reginald](https://github.com/michaeltyson/Reginald) ([screenshot](http://atastypixel.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/201007312318.jpg))

A few online editors:

- [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)
- [MyRegexp](http://myregexp.com/)

And if you're willing to run windows in a virtual machine, there's also the Regex overlord:

- [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: And so do I. :) And Reginald for the more tricky ones.

Comment: +1 for RegexBuddy - many years later on a well-provisioned VM even the old version is much less frustrating to work with

Answer (score 2):

I like regexhibit, there are some others here:

http://alternativeto.net/software/regexhibit/?platform=mac

Or if as others have said you don't mind running a VM I think regex coach for Windows is a little better:

http://weitz.de/regex-coach/

Comment: Updated link for regexhibit http://roger-jolly.nl/software/

Answer (score 0):

There are two that I can think of, both rely on PyQt, the [eric ide](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/), this is a nice python ide, it is specialized for PyQt but has a regex tool built into it. The other is [kodos](http://kodos.sourceforge.net/home.html) which is a standalone regex tool.

Answer (score 0):

A self-plug:

http://motionobj.com/regex

You can also read the tutorial here http://motionobj.com/blog/regex-macos-tutorial. Although it mentions the Regex app, it should still be helpful with other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [iRegEx](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iregex/id480467177).